# Flutter close a dialog and reload page with filtered list of the condition selected

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter_event_app/constant/color.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/network/models/categories.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/network/models/event_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/network/models/time.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/network/services/event_api.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/pages/event_detail_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/pages/search/home_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/widgets/event_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/widgets/no_events.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_app/widgets/onload.dart';

class SelectedCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  // SelectedCategory(Categories categories);

  final Categories categories;
  final Time time;
  SelectedCategory(this.categories, [this.time]);

  @override
  _SelectedCategoryState createState() => _SelectedCategoryState();
}

class _SelectedCategoryState extends State<SelectedCategory> {
  Categories categories;
  Time timing;

  String timeselect;

  // Event event;

  void viewEventDetail(Events event) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, animation, __) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: EventDetailPage(event),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Events> upcomingEvents;

  List categorizedupcomingEvents = [];
  List categorizedPaidupcomingEvents = [];
  List categorizedFreeupcomingEvents = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchData();

    categories = widget.categories;
    timing = widget.time;

    // print(timing.id);

    super.initState();
  }

  Future _fetchData() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);

    upcomingEvents = await getEventss();

    categorizedupcomingEvents = upcomingEvents
        .where((category) => category.category == categories.id)
        .toList();

    categorizedPaidupcomingEvents = categorizedupcomingEvents
        .where((paid) => paid.is_paid == true)
        .toList();
    categorizedFreeupcomingEvents = categorizedupcomingEvents
        .where((free) => free.is_paid == false)
        .toList();

    setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9.5,
            ),
            child: AppBar(
              title: Text(categories.categoryName),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.sort,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //     context,
                      //     MaterialPageRoute(
                      //         builder: (context) =>
                      showFilterByTimeDialog(context);
                      // )
                      // );
                    }),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {})
              ],
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Text('All'),
                  Text('Paid'),
                  Text('Free'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              // All
              isLoading
                  ? OnloadingCards()
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: categorizedupcomingEvents.isEmpty
                                ? NoItems()
                                : ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: categorizedupcomingEvents.length,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    primary: false,
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      final event =
                                          categorizedupcomingEvents[index];
                                      return EventCard(event,
                                          onTap: () => viewEventDetail(event));
                                    },
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

              // Paid
              isLoading
                  ? OnloadingCards()
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: categorizedPaidupcomingEvents.isEmpty
                                ? NoItems()
                                : ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount:
                                        categorizedPaidupcomingEvents.length,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    primary: false,
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      final event =
                                          categorizedPaidupcomingEvents[index];
                                      return EventCard(event,
                                          onTap: () => viewEventDetail(event));
                                    },
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

              // Free
              isLoading
                  ? OnloadingCards()
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: categorizedFreeupcomingEvents.isEmpty
                                ? NoItems()
                                : ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount:
                                        categorizedFreeupcomingEvents.length,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    primary: false,
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      final event =
                                          categorizedFreeupcomingEvents[index];
                                      return EventCard(event,
                                          onTap: () => viewEventDetail(event));
                                    },
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }





  void showFilterByTimeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Dialog fancyDialog = Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            // color: Colors.greenAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                child: Text(
                  "Time",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    width: double.infinity,

                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: times.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          Time time = times[index];

                          return RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              debugPrint('I am Awesome');
                            },
                            textColor: Colors.red,
                            // color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                            disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
                            highlightColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                            child: Text(time.name),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
        context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => fancyDialog);
  }
}
```

Within the same page I have a dialog box as shown below

On the method *`showFilterByTimeDialog`* where I select an item and have to go back to the same page below the dialogue .Am still learning flutter and my issue is I need help when I select an item from the dialogue box,i refresh the same page and display a new filtered lst from the current list displayed on that page with a condition of the item selected from the dialogue box.